# Error: "Unexpected Symbol" when defining expression

Tags: r

I'm in a statistics and data analysis class that recently started using R. I'm getting an error message and so far I haven't been able to determine exactly what the error is or how to fix it.

We were given instructions to plot this function:

```
y=0.1x^4-0.5x^3-x^2+3x-2
```

The next instruction asks to follow this coding and enter the above function:

```
> x<-seq(-5,5,by=2)
> y<- ## enter the function, here
> plot(y~x)
> lines(y~x)
```

This is what I get when I enter the function in `y`:

```
> x<-seq(-5, 5, by=2)
> y<-0.1x^4-0.5x^3-x^2+3x-2
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "y<-0.1x"

Is the unexpected symbol the `x`? I tried removing the decimals in the function to test it out but get the same error message:

```
> y<-x^4-5x^3-x^2+3x-2
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "y<-x^4-5x"

So I'm thinking it's the `x` that is the problem, but how do I fix it? I ran the `x` sequence code with no problem.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really the right place for a question like this, I think. I think you will be much better off seeking out help from your classmates, your instructor, or simply reading a basic [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html).

Comment: You will find that that particular error message generally means you have forgotten a comma or some other "punctuation character". The R interpreter saw a variable named "5x" and that is not a legal name in R, which does not allow names to begin with numerals.

Comment: not identical but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358987/errorattempt-to-apply-non-function/16365614#16365614

Answer (score 7):

In algebra, two symbols next to each other (e.g. `0.1` and `x` in `0.1x`) imply they are multiplied. In programming, that assumption is not made and an explicit multiplication operator is needed: `0.1*x`.

Answer (score 3):

Try x * 0.5 instead of x0.5.

Although, I do not use RStudio.