# Error:attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm trying to run the following code in R, but I'm getting an error.

I'm not sure what part of the formula is incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
> censusdata_20$AGB93 = WD * exp(-1.239 + 1.980 * log (DIAM93) + 0.207 (log(DIAM93))^2 
                        - 0.0281 (log(DIAM93))^3)
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Answer (score 49):

You're missing `*`s in the last two terms of your expression, so R is interpreting (e.g.) `0.207 (log(DIAM93))^2` as an attempt to call a function named `0.207` ...

For example:

```
> 1 + 2*(3)
[1] 7
> 1 + 2 (3)
```

> Error: attempt to apply non-function

Your (unreproducible) expression should read:

```
censusdata_20$AGB93 = WD * exp(-1.239 + 1.980 * log (DIAM93) + 
                              0.207* (log(DIAM93))^2  -
                              0.0281*(log(DIAM93))^3)
```

Mathematica is the only computer system I know of that allows juxtaposition to be used for multiplication ...

Comment: Does the error literally mean that one is trying to call a function (*apply*) on something that's not a function?

Comment: the "non-function" is 0.207.  `0.207 (log(DIAM93))` is interpreted as calling the function "0.207" with the argument "log(DIAM93)"

Answer (score 1):

I got the error because of a clumsy **typo**:

This errors:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$seet(echo = FALSE)
```

> Error: attempt to apply non-function

After correcting the typo, it works:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```